# Display a custom post type list by taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-list-pages, categories

I need to show a list of custom post type classified by terms. The idea is something like this:

Service list:

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <a href="#">Webdesign (taxonomy term)</a>
   <ul>
     <li>Business Website A (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
     <li>Business Website B (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
     <li>Business Website C (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
   <a href="#">Illustration (taxonomy term)</a>
   <ul>
     <li>Business Illustration A (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
     <li>Business Illustration B (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
     <li>Business Illustration C (custom post type from this taxonomy term)</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Other service without taxonomy (if has no taxonomy, show in first level)</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried the wp_list_pages and wp_list_categories, but without success. Could someone give me a hint how to proceed?

Comment: Question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16300903/1981996

Comment: I need a little more information on how to do. Could you help me?

Comment: @Brightweb Multi-posts are very bad. You ask us to duplicate others work. Really?